# Convexity : question and conditions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

It's just a question about convexity I would like to know if a function $f(x)$ with $x\in [0;\infty[$ is convex if we have the following conditions :

1)$f(x)\ge x$ for all  $x\in [0;\infty[$

2)$f(x)$ have a global minimum on $[0;\infty[$

3)$f(x)$ have a third derivate on $[0;\infty[$

4)$f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[0;\infty[$ .

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $f(x) = x + \ln (x+1)$

(Note: with the requirement 'strictly increasing' you will always have the global minimum in $x=0$).

Comment: Thanks it's short and efficient (+1) . If we add the condition $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=f'(c)$ and if know that the $c$ is unique and the tangent  is below the secant it is convex and if yes have you a proof ? thanks again .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this works. Put $f(x)=\sin(x) + 2x +1$. Then
$f(x)\geq 2x\geq x$, since $\sin x\geq -1$. This gives you 1). 4) is proven by deriving:
$$f'(x)=\cos(x)+2 > 0.$$
$f$ is smooth, therefore 3) is satisfied. 4) implies 2), i.e. $f$ has a global minimum in $0$. But
$$f''(x)=-\sin(x),$$
which can be positive and negativ, therefore $f$ is not convex